# Storing obfuscated password in bash variable to write to file later

Tags: bash, pipe, printf, echo, vnc

I currently have a script that is attempting to generate a new VNC password.

When I enter the string `0987poiu)(*&POIU` into my script, it generates *almost* identical output to the `vncpasswd` utility. This comparison is done by comparing the two generated `~/.vnc/passwd` files.

#### ISSUE / SSCCE

There is a difference between

```
my_input='0987poiu)(*&POIU'
test_var=$(echo $my_input | vncpasswd -f)
echo $test_var > /home/test_file_1
```

and

```
my_input='0987poiu)(*&POIU'
echo $my_input | vncpasswd -f > /home/test_file_2
```

I've tried using `echo $my_input | tr -d '\n'` to remove any newline characters to no avail. I've also used `printf` in place of `echo`, which also did not work.

Storing the obfuscated password into a variable and using `echo` or `printf` to pipe that variable into a file does not work.

I am able to get `echo $my_input | vncpasswd -f > /home/test_file2` to match the output of `~/.vnc/passwd` that was generated by the `vncpasswd` utility, but that is not the desired order of operations and I would like to store the output of `vncpasswd -f` into a variable to use later on in the script.

```
$ hexdump test_file_1
00000000 1921 65e6 2aaa 1c20 000a
00000009

$ hexdump test_file_2
00000000 1921 65e6 2aaa 1c09
00000008
```

Comment: You need to quote your parameter expansions. Unquoted expansions are subject to word-splitting and pathname generation.

Comment: What exactly does `vncpasswd` output? The command substitution will strip trialing newlines.

Comment: @chepner the `vncpasswd -f` command will generate an obfuscated password that `vnc` uses for authentication purposes. Essentially it will generate the content I need to place in the `~/.vnc/passwd` file that `vnc` uses.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. To be specific, can the value it outputs end with a newline character?

Comment: @chepner Sorry, no the generated value will not end with a new line character.

Comment: You claim there is a difference between `test_file_1` and `test_file_2`. Could you *share* what that difference is?

Comment: @chepner
    `cmp -b --verbose test_file_1 test_file_2`
    `7  11  ^I        40`
    `cmp: EOF on test_file_1`

Comment: @chepner added hexdump output to question above. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `echo` commands add a newline to the value you actually want to use. Use `printf` instead. Unquoted parameter expansions may account for trailing whitespace from being eliminated from the parameter value.

```
my_input='0987poiu)(*&POIU'
test_var=$(printf '%s' "$my_input" | vncpasswd -f)
printf '%s' "$test_var" > /home/test_file_1
```

Comment: Cheers. Thanks for the help @chepner